# await SecureStorage.GetAsync("Key"); returns null

Tags: c#, xamarin

### Description

```
await SecureStorage.GetAsync("Key"); returns null for Android OS.
```

SecureStorage works everywhere else in Xamarin forms project.

It even works if I store value in IFunction2 >> Invoke & try to retrieve it.
Value are not getting preserved in MainActivity>>OnCreate too.

### Steps to Reproduce

Reproduce 1

- Store token in MyFirebaseMessagingService (firebase service)>> OnNewToken
- Try to retrive token in callbase IFunction2 >> Invoke
- returns null.

Reproduce 2

- Store some string in main activity >> on create
- try to retrieve it in second run
- returns null

Expected Behavior: string should be persisted

Actual Behavior: null result

```
Basic Information
Version with issue: 1.5.3.2
Last known good version: not known
IDE: VS for mac
Platform Target Frameworks:
Android: 10
Nuget Packages: Xamarin.Essentials
Affected Devices: nova 3i
```

Comment: have you read the extensive notes about Android in the docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to add:

```
<manifest ... >
    ...
    <application android:allowBackup="false" ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and you can always use a default value (just in case)

```
 await SecureStorage.SetAsync("oauth_token", "secret-oauth-token-value");
```

More documentation in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=android

Comment: From what I'm reading on that page, that isn't a prerequisite to setting up secure storage for android, rather it's an optional setting and shouldn't stop it from working. I've tried disabling backups and still getting the same issue with the method returning null in my code also.